# How to add a customized image button to UINavigationBar in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone

I want to add customized arrow buttons to UINavigation Bar which comes at the top.

what I want to do is create a custom image button and place it over the bar. When I tried adding to view like:

```
[self.view addSubview:leftArrowButton];//(Where leftArrowButton is a UIButton with an image of arrow)
```

This dont work, like it places the button but button gets hided under the bar and not overlap on it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try doing the following:

```
UINavigationBar *bar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
bar.titleView = leftArrowButton;  // change title view
bar.leftBarButtonItem = leftArrowButton; // if ref is UIBarButtonItem
```

You should consider using a `UIBarButtonItem` rather than `UIButton`.

You can also customize the bar buttons as well with images (using the [`initWithImage:style:target:action:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithImage:style:target:action:)):

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:myImage
                             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                            target:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)];
bar.leftBarButtonItem = item;
[item release];
```

You can also use any view you like (with some consideration for the size) using the [`initWithCustomView:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithCustomView:):

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                           initWithCustomView:leftArrowButton];
bar.leftBarButtonItem = item;
[item release];
```

Comment: I know I can use barButtonItem but then I cant customize the button. I want to customize the button.

Comment: Updated post to describe how to customize `UIBarButtonItem`.