# Adding image to Navigation bar in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationbar

I have added Navigation bar and Navigation Item in xib. Now I need to add image to the left of Navigation bar, but its not getting added.
This is the code I'm working on:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"i_launcher.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;
    [imageView release];
}
```

I can't understand why the image is not getting added. How can I add it?

Comment: check my answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488710/how-to-set-a-picture-programmatically-in-a-navbar#comment18517078_13488710

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to display an image in the navigation bar of an iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844416/how-to-display-an-image-in-the-navigation-bar-of-an-iphone-application)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage) -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect { 

     CGRect currentRect = CGRectMake(0,0,100,45); 
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_launcher.png"]; 
     [image drawInRect:currentRect]; 
} 
@end
```

**UPDATE**

just add this code in your `viewDidLoad:` method..

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]];
UIBarButtonItem * item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage2.jpg"]]];    
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
```

and also if you want to direct set image in background of NavigationBar then use bellow line...

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"i_launcher.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

also see this Link [how-to-add-a-customized-image-button-to-uinavigationbar-in-iphone-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239599/how-to-add-a-customized-image-button-to-uinavigationbar-in-iphone-sdk)

i hope this help you...

Comment: @Esha see this link how-to-add-image-in-uinavigationbar-in-iphone-app

Comment: I have added it in ViewDidLoad .But I m getting errors:"Unexpected @ in program.. and so on..Where should I add it ?

Comment: just above of your @implementation yourViewController class, out of your class code

Comment: @Esha create image with your requirement and add this image as a background of your navigationbar and set background image with my second code try this...

Comment: I got ur code given this to be  working :@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
     CGRect currentRect = CGRectMake(0,0,100,45);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_launcher.png"]; [image     
                                                 drawInRect:currentRect]; }
@end .

Comment: but a little bit problem .When I go with this code it changes the blue background colour of navigation bar to white.Y is it so?What I need is I need the background of image to be white.As I have said I have to add image to left side and in center title.I need the background of left over part after image to be in blue colour.How can I do it ?

Comment: @Esha just add this code     [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

Comment: @Esha also try second option with update its also work fine otherwise set the titntcolor of navigationbar

Comment: I added the code [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]]; but still background colour did n't change

Comment: when i try to add ur updated code image itself is not getting displayed

Comment: first comment my default code which you implement and try with this otherwise create one image with your whole navigationbar which you want and then add background image to navigationbar

Comment: No still I dont get it.I just got with @implementation code only.So tell me how can I change only the background part with image to be in white colour.

Comment: you try this self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]];
UIBarButtonItem * item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage2.jpg"]]];    
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item; ??

Comment: no luck.I think it is bcoz I added navigation bar programatically.Can 't I change only the background part of image to be in white colour with ur code?

Comment: @Esha [yourNaviGationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"i_launcher.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]; try this with also try this [yourNavigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]]; and just change some code its working all just setting with your requirement ..

Comment: see I have created a ViewBased application.In appDelegate.m I added this -

Comment: (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{ViewController *first=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];  
Login *second=[[Login alloc]initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:nil]; second.title=@"Login";NSArray *viewArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: first,second,nil];tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];[tabBarController setViewControllers:viewArray animated:NO];[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; [viewArray release];return YES;
 }

Comment: To ViewController I added a ScrollView and a navigation bar to a ScrollView through xib.So I dont have any navigation bar code

Comment: you give the outlet or referacnce to the navigationbar??

Comment: one more doubt.Suppose I have added another navigation bar in same viewcontroller then I should not get image for it .How can I get it ?by using tag?

Comment: yes just give different name and hide and show the navigation bar bt why you add two navbar??

Comment: when i give different name aso im getting the image attached to another navigation bar also

Comment: i think you give the image with self.navigatio... but insted of use with navigationbar name

Comment: one more things y is the image getting added to all the navigation controllers of all ViewControllers when I add it only to a specific ViewController?@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage) -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect { 

     CGRect currentRect = CGRectMake(0,0,100,45); 
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_launcher.png"]; 
     [image drawInRect:currentRect]; 
} 
@end

Comment: hey its happen bcoz another viewcontroller are child control of this class so its the same navigationcontroller, if u want to change it then give the another view or change the style of navigationcontrol thats it.. and if this answer useful to u then dont forget to accept answer or upvote it thank you.. :) and if u want to use this navbar view in same view then in another view set  another view or use this self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack; or another style.. i hope u understand :)

Answer (score 8):

Looks like this is an old question with an accepted answer.  However, I wanted to add:

In at least Xcode 5, **if you are using storyboards** then you can add the image as the navigationBar's title by dragging an empty view into the title area, and then placing the ImageView inside the empty view.

The following screenshot should give you an idea of how it looks:
[image: Storyboard screenshot depicting imageView inside of empty view inside the navigationBar.titleView]

Answer (score 4):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

    {


       UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Your Image"];
       UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
       imageView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 10, 72, 19);
       [self.navViewController.navigationBar addSubview:imageView];
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set your image at particular point in navigation bar then you can make a view and then add your image inside the view, adjust your image frame and then add this view to your navBar.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
[image setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
[view addSubview:image];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:view];
```

If you are adding NavBar from xib then just make `IBOutlet` for your `UINavigationBar` connect it in xib then

```
[myNavigationBar addSubview:view];
```

Comment: No I didnt get it . As I have said I added navigation bar through xib and so these codes are not getting recognized....

Answer (score 1):

**`For Swift 4:`**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // 1
        let nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar

        // 2
        nav?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
        nav?.tintColor = UIColor.yellow

        // 3
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        // 4
        let image = UIImage(named: "Apple_Swift_Logo")
        imageView.image = image

        // 5
        navigationItem.titleView = imageView
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the **imageView.frame** also please cross check the **image initailized** properly

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"i_launcher.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
imageView.frame.origin.x = 30.0; // You will have to find suitable values for the origin
imageView.frame.origin.y = 5.0;
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;
[imageView release];
```

Comment: getting error :Expression is not assignable at this line imageView.frame.origin.x = 30.0;

Comment: Did like this  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"i_launcher.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
    imageView.frame =CGRectMake(0,0,50,50);// You will have to find suitable values for the origin
    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;
    [imageView release]; Stil couldnot c d image added ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok. But I don't know why you need to add navigation bar and item in xib. If you create your own view controller derived from UIViewController, it has contained navigation bar. You may try to remove yourself added navigation bar and item from xib and see what's happen.

If you want to show nav bar on the first view of a view-based application, you need to modify your application class code as below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];

    // REMOVE THIS LINE !!!!!!!!!!!!!
    //self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

    // ADD BELOW TWO LINES !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

I just did a test like the following:

1. Create a new single-view based project.
2. Run it without any modification. It will show an empty screen.
3. Modify didFinishLaunchingWithOptions() as above in the application.m file.
4. In the viewcontroller.m, add the following lines.

   -(void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];
   UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
   view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"];
   self.navigationItem.titleView = view;
   }
5. Now run again. You will see a nav bar with a image as title.

Comment: but i dont see the navigation bar added automatically on running viewbased application unless I add it externally.So I have added externally to my View Controller

Comment: I have added code in answer. I just tested those code, it works.

Comment: I added ur code and then in view controller added my code.Still it doesnot show any navigation bar to me

Comment: Did you remove yourself-added nav bar from xib?

Comment: yes i removed it .it is a view based application.I added ur code in Appdelegate.m

Comment: I just did a test, it works. Please see my answer update. You may try it also.

Comment: I my view I have a scrollview and I m adding navigation bar to it thrugh xib

Comment: I dont have  single-view based project in xcode 4.1.So gone with view based project.but if I did as u have said then I m getting an empty white view

Comment: My xcode is latest. I have no way to test on xcode 4.1. But I don't believe it's xcode difference. View-based project is same as single-view based project, apple just renamed since xcode 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you sure. if not work mean check your image name is correct.

```
UIImage *yourimage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"i_launcher.png"];

UIButton *buttonBarButton = [ UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
buttonBarButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,yourimage.size.width,yourimage.size.height);
[buttonBarButton setBackgroundImage:yourimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonBarButton addTarget:nil action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *buttonBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:buttonBarButton] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = buttonBarButtonItem;
```

if you wish add action means :

```
[buttonBarButton addTarget:self action:@selector(your function) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide / show the image between movements to another controller do this.  Adjust the CGRectMake dimensions accordingly.

Add this to your header file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIImageView *navBarLogo;
```

Add this to your .m controller file:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(53, 7, 210, 30);

    self.navBarLogo = imageView;

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imageView];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar sendSubviewToBack:self.navBarLogo];
}
```